# How to retrieve the first 4 images from post format image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I used this code to retrieve the first 4 videos that resides inside the video post format input.

```
$args = array( 'category-name' => 'galeria-videos', 'numberposts' => 4 );
wp_reset_postdata();
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$ytlink = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post);
    $e = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_video');
    array_push($ytlink, $e[0]);
endforeach;
```

But now I need to retrieve the first 4 images inside the post format gallery (single image or gallery), so i tried this without success:

```
$args = array( 'category-name' => 'galeria-imagens', 'numberposts' => 4 );
wp_reset_postdata();
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$imglink = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post);
    $e = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_gallery');
    array_push($imglink, $e[0]);
endforeach;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What not working? any error? what output you get? You're not passing any `post-format` arguments?

Comment: I'm getting the post meta inside the `foreach` loop. I'm receiving array with `NULL`s when I `var_dump` the `$imglink` var

Comment: wp_reset_postdata should go at the end of the foreach, not there. I suggest to take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts